# não sei por onde começar alguém pra me ajudar?

Tags: javascript

Leia duas matrizes A e B (5 X 5) de números inteiros
e, a partir delas, gere a matriz SOMA (correspondente a soma das duas
matrizes: A + B) e a matriz SUBTRACAO (correspondente à subtração entre
as duas matrizes: A - B).

O que fiz até agora é:

```js
var matrizA= [
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[] 
];
var matrizB=[ 
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[],
  [],[],[],[],[] 
];
for (var linha = 0; linha <= 4; linha++) {
  matrizA = prompt("digite 5 valores para matrizA: ");
  matrizB = prompt("digite 5 valores para matrizB: ")
  for (var coluna = 0; coluna <= 4; coluna++) {
    matrizA[linha][coluna] = matrizB[linha][coluna] = (linha + 1) + (coluna + 1);
    document.write("[" + (linha + 1) + "] + [" + (coluna + 1) + "] =" + matrizA[linha][coluna] + matrizB[linha][coluna] + "<br>");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Oi, copiei o que colocaste em comentário para a pergunta. Podes sempre [edit] a pergunta para a clarificar. Evita mudar o direção da pergunta, mas para clarificar é bom editar.

Comment: ok entendi. fim outra tentativa onde eu consigo percorrer a linha da matrizA quanto a coluna da matrizB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu leio essa pergunta assim:

> Cria duas arrays, com números inteiros.
>   Depois gera uma nova matriz onde cada posição contém a soma dos respectivos números nas outras matrizes.
>   Depois gera uma nova matriz onde cada posição contém a soma dos respectivos números nas outras matrizes.

Não sei como queres adicionar esses números, mas no caso de já os teres, podes criar novas arrays com o `.map()` pois o que queres são novas arrays com a mesma estrutura mas com as somas/subtrações...

Um exemplo seria:

```js
const a = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]

const b = [
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
]

const AmenosB = a.map((arraydeCinco, i) => {
  return arraydeCinco.map((numero, x) => {
    return numero - b[i][x];
  });
});
const AmaisB = a.map((arraydeCinco, i) => {
  return arraydeCinco.map((numero, x) => {
    return numero + b[i][x];
  });
});

console.log('AmenosB', JSON.stringify(AmenosB));
console.log('AmaisB', JSON.stringify(AmaisB));
```

Como tens muito código duplicado podes simplificar assim:

```js
const a = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]

const b = [
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
]


const calc = (arrA, arrB, sign) => {
  return arrA.map((arr, i) => {
    return arr.map((numero, x) => {
      return numero + (arrB[i][x] * sign);
    });
  });
}

const AmenosB = calc(a, b, -1);
const AmaisB = calc(a, b, 1);


console.log('AmenosB', JSON.stringify(AmenosB));
console.log('AmaisB', JSON.stringify(AmaisB));
```

O mesmo exemplo com um `for` poderia ser:

```js
const a = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]

const b = [
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
]

const AmenosB = [];
const AmaisB = [];
for (let x = 0, lx = a.length; x < lx; x++) {
  const soma = [];
  const diff = [];
  for (let y = 0, ly = a[x].length; y < ly; y++) {
    soma.push(a[x][y] + b[x][y]);
    diff.push(a[x][y] - b[x][y]);
  }
  AmenosB.push(diff);
  AmaisB.push(soma);
}

console.log('AmenosB', JSON.stringify(AmenosB));
console.log('AmaisB', JSON.stringify(AmaisB));
```

Comment: você pode me explicar como eu usaria com um laço for?

Comment: @anamarialeiteramos o `.map()` faz o mesmo que o laço `for` só que aproveita o resultado. Podes fazer com `for` também mas tens de usar mais linhas...

Comment: ah, ok entendi. valeu mesmo!!

Comment: @anamarialeiteramos juntei também um exemplo com `for`

Comment: realmente com o map fica muito mais simples e menor o código